# Lucene MoreLikeThis cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, lucene, recommendation-engine, morelikethis

I'm trying to use MoreLikeThis class from lucene as described in "Lucene in action" book, but that class does not seem to exist :/

I'm using lucene-core-2.9.4.jar, normal indexing and searching works fine.
I have looked iniside the jar (and the 3.x.x version), but there is no such class inside, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referring to the [MoreLikeThis](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_4/api/contrib-queries/org/apache/lucene/search/similar/MoreLikeThis.html) class? It should be inside lucene-queries-2.9.4.jar. Look under the contrib/queries folder of your Lucene binary download.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this page: http://www.manning.com/hatcher2/ and download the source code. The class MoreLikeThis is not part of lucene itself, rather an example class related to the book

Comment: Hmm, although I can't see if in the source tree. Is the class file definitely called MoreLikeThis?